# UITableview scroll to top of the index position when move to another page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an `UITableView`, if I move to the another screen and when I come back to the `UITableView` screen the scroll automatically stops at 1st index position, how can I overcome it.

Thanks.

Comment: use tableview.reloadData on your viewWillAppear

Comment: do you want to get rid of scrolling to first indexPath?

Comment: `[tableView reloadData]` is not responsible for scroll unless the data is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Override `viewWillAppear` method like below and scroll to first IndexPath,

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tblList.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

For Objective-C,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [tblList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question and description are contradictory, either you want the tableview to remain at same position when user comes back to the page, or you want the tableview to scroll to top. If you go with first option then this solution could help you, for the second option you refer to PPL answer.

Save the tableview content offset before your push to another page.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  tableViewContentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
 }
```

and set tableview offset again in viewWillAppear

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self.tableView setContentOffset:tableViewContentOffset];
 }
```

Comment: https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/71149d , there are other alternative solution too

Answer (score 0):

For Objective c

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:self.sectionToShow];
[cont.tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to finish your data fetching and calling of `reloadData` method of `UITableView` into `viewDidLoad` method of your `UIViewController`.

So whenever you move to another scene your previous screen will remain as it is, because `viewDidLoad` only called once when your `UIViewController` is initialized.

Comment: Can you please share your codes of data fetching, reloadData, etc. so everyone can get better idea.